# Cut the second field delimited by spaces

Tags: bash, cut-command

I want to retrieve the second column from `ps` result:

```
test@pc:~$ ps -e | head -5 | cut -d '' -f1
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:03 systemd
    2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
    3 ?        00:00:00 rcu_gp
    4 ?        00:00:00 rcu_par_gp
```

It does not work, I learned that it could be solve the a complicated way as:

```
test@pc:~$ ps -e | head -5 | gawk '{print $2}'
TTY
?
?
?
?
```

How could solve the problem with the generic tool of `cut`?

Comment: If you are especially after the output of `ps`: you can control what columns it prints with the `-o` (for output) switch like so: `ps -e -o tname`. Here `tname` is the column ID to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we replace each sequence of a repeated spaces using `tr -s ' '` then we grab the 3th column:

```
ps -e | head -5 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f3
```

3th column because there is a space at the beginning of each line. We can remove that too:

```
ps -e | head -5 | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/ //' | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

Comment: so amazing your answer.